# pass radio button value to filter

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I am having the below data:-

```
   Var1            Freq year
1 United States 600015 1906
2 United States 533209 1811
3 China         465852 1906
4 China         438228 1811
5 Japan         117248 1906
6 Japan         109436 1811
7 France         67183 1906
8 Germany        60503 1811
9 Germany        59140 1906
10 France         43580 1811
```

So i wanted to plot a bar chart which consists of a radio button for 1811 and 1906, with radio button selected 1811 should print the processed data frame & databar chart with 1811 values.

I am trying to use the below code

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel(h1("Chart", align = "center", style = "color:black")),
    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    radioButtons("radio","Radio buttons",choices = list("1906" = 1906, "1811" = 1811),selected = 1906),
    actionButton("goButton","Analyze")),
    mainPanel(
    fluidRow(splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "100%"),DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"),plotOutput("Plot",height=550)))
    )))

server <- function(input, output) {

    #yrdt <- filter(all_datay, all_datay$year %in% c('1906',''))
    yrdt <- filter(all_datay, all_datay$year %in% c('input$radio')
    pltyrdt <- head(yrdt,10)

    output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(yrdt, class = 'cell-border stripe', colnames = c('Rank', 'Country', 'Freq', 'Year'))})

    output$Plot <- renderPlot({
            input$goButton
    barplot(pltyrdt$Freq,names.arg=pltyrdt$Var1,horiz=F,xlab="Country",ylab="Freq", yaxs="i", xaxs="i")})

    output$value <- renderPrint({ input$radio })
    }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am facing the below error

> Error: need finite 'xlim' values.

Can anyone help me.

If i selected the data only for 1906 then the output is as shown in the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems.

- `'input$radio'` is in quotes. It is a string, literally `input$radio` (and not the value). Should you remove the quotes (`'`), you get an error message which tells you actually what the problem is, namely that
- you  try to use `input$radio` outside of a reactive environment.

Basically, you call the `filter` function once during server setup and ask it to get all the rows where year is equal to `input$radio` (not the contents of the reactive variable `input$radio`, but the literal string `input$radio`). Thus, yrdt is empty.

Here is one option:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    yrdt <- function() { filter(all_datay, all_datay$year %in% input$radio) }

    output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({ 
      datatable(yrdt(), class = 'cell-border stripe', 
                        colnames = c('Rank', 'Country', 'Freq', 'Year'))})

    output$Plot <- renderPlot({
            input$goButton
            pltyrdt <- head(yrdt(),10)
            barplot(pltyrdt$Freq, 
                    names.arg=pltyrdt$Var1,
                    horiz=F,
                    xlab="Country", ylab="Freq", 
            yaxs="i", xaxs="i")
    })

    output$value <- renderPrint({ input$radio })
```

}

What happens here is that you define a function that can compute the selection, and which is called when needed. Since it is called from within a reactive environment (such as `renderPlot()`), `input$radio` works as intended.

Alternatively, you can define `yrdt` as a reactive expression:

```
yrdt <- reactive({filter(all_datay, all_datay$year %in% input$radio) })
...
    pltyrdt <- head(yrdt(),10)
```

(you use it just like you would use the function above).

More on reactive environments in shiny [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html).

Comment: Thanks Ronak. It is working as expected. But without clicking the analyze button itslef the report is generated. Can you let me know how can i do that.

Comment: Also is there any way to select multiple radio buttons at once. Thanks

Comment: ad 1: if you want to avoid it, put `isolate()` around `input$radio` (see [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/isolation.html)). Regarding second question, what you want are [checkboxes](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/checkboxInput.html). Radiobuttons by definition can be selected only one at the time.

Comment: thanks, but it is not working. Here is my code     yrdt <- reactive ({filter(all_datay, all_datay$year %in% isolate({ input$radio }))})   can you let me know if there is any error.

Comment: No need for the curly brackets, just write `isolate(input$radio)`.

Comment: Thanks but the isolate(input$radio) is not working. If i refresh the page after selection then it is functioning as expected if not it is showing the default value data only.       datasum <-  reactive ({as.data.frame(as.table(tapply(data$'Rmax [TFlop/s]', data$input$radio, sum)))})   i am facing issue again when using the reactive here. Can you help me in this

Comment: Sorry, but this is really a different question and your lack of formatting makes it hard to understand what your problem is. You are doing something wrong, but I cannot tell what without seeing more of your code. Please start another question and hope someone will respond; I will not, as apparently you are not happy with my answers.

Comment: Thank you. I am unable to get the isolate option work in the above posted code.